# scraping external javascript files using Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri

I need to crawl several URLs and grab their contents into a DB.

the crawled data must contain both the HTML and external CSS and JS files.

I used Nokogiri to grab CSS with no problem but am unable to get the Javacript as easily..

here is my relevant code:

...

```
arrJS = []
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) 
page.css('script').map {|link| arrJS << link['src'].to_s}
```

...

when I use this on a site like yahoo.com - I get a wierd arrJS array that has no relevance to the javascripts on the html.

any thoughts?

Comment: What "weird" array do you get? I don't see why this shouldn't work (except for `<script>` tags without a `src` attribute)

Comment: I will handle the acceptance thing right away.

Comment: the wierd response is an array  that looks like

[["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "http://l.yimg.com/zz/combo?nn/lib/metro/g/uicontrib/yui/yui_3.4.1.js", "", "", "", "", ""], ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "http://l.yimg.com/zz/combo?nn/lib/metro/g/uicontrib/yui/yui_3.4.1.js", "", "", "", "", ""], ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "http://l.yimg.com/zz/combo?nn/lib/metro/g/uicontrib/yui/yui_3.4.1.js", "", "", "", "", ""], ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "http://l.yimg.com/zz/combo?nn/lib/metro/g/uicontrib/yui/yui_3.4.1.js", "", "", "", "", ""],..

Comment: @NighOwl: As I said, the empty strings mean that the corresponding `script` tags don't have a `src` attribute. Also you should use `each` instead of `map` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `Array#map` with `Array#each`. Try this

```
arrJS = []
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

page.css('script').each do |script|
    src = script['src']
    arrJS << src.to_s unless src.nil?
end
```

This will give you the content of all the `src` attributes of all the `script` elements.

If, instead, you want the *content* of the inlined scripts, not the source URI, you can use

```
contentJS = []

page.css('script').each do |script|
    contentJS << script.content if script['src'].nil?
end
```